# PHP : object method+proprety call from var

Tags: php, object

I want to call an object method+property with the content stored in a var ...
for example :

```
// setup the object
$xpath = new DOMXpath();

// setup the 'method'+'property' to call 
$var1 = "query('something')->item(O)->nodeValue";
$return = $xpath->$var1();
```

Obviously, I make a mistake ... assuming that direct call is working, i.e.:

```
$return2 = $xpath->query('something')->item(0)->value;
echo "Return2 : ".$return2; //print okeedokee ...
```

How to pass args to query()? And how to add extra args to it?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?? Whatever it is, $xpath->$var1(); makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to call

```
$return=$xpath->$var1;
```

Note : [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) is the function you need

Example :

#### alpha.php

```
class Alpha
{
   public function getAlpha($arr_input)
   {
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($arr_input);
   }
}
```

#### index.php

```
include_once 'alpha.php';
$post = array('one','two','three');
$obj_alpha =  new Alpha();

call_user_func( array( $obj_alpha , 'getAlpha' ), $post ) ;
//here I call `getAlpha` function from object of class alpha (`$obj_alpha`) 
  with argument `$post`

//will print $post array
```

Comment: I've been looking at it ...
but I'm unable to make it working with the object ... and I did't find any example on the web.

Maybe you can provide one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using eval():

```
$return = eval('return $xpath->' . $var1 .';');
```

However, using eval() with user-input is pretty much always a bad idea. So be careful there.

Comment: the 'eval' approach works fine in this case ...

thank's to everybody
:)